# I need compatible JavaScript code for document.createElementNS() in older versions of IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

The JavaScript function [`document.createElementNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElementNS) does not work in older versions of IE (6,7,8)? Is there any compatible code for this function, like  `Array`'s [compatible map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for old version IE?

Comment: Which version of IE do you mean specifically?

Comment: IEs do not support svg, like 6,7 and 8

Comment: Could you perhaps post the javascript code using and including **document.createElementNS()**? In a http://jsfiddle.net if possible.

Comment: var img = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");            img.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "move.png");

Comment: The first parameter of createElementNS is a string. There is an unnecessary semi-colon (;) in there. Remove that. Also for setAttributeNS.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following google group post. There's a workaround that may help you:
http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/issues/detail?id=625

Workaround (from link above):

```
window.onload = function() {
    function onCreateElementNsReady(func) {
        if (document.createElementNS != undefined) {
            func();
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() { onCreateElementNsReady(func); }, 100);
        }
    }

    onCreateElementNsReady(function() {
        var svg = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'svg');
        // ...
    });
};
```