# createElementNS not working in ie8

Tags: javascript, svg

I created svg element with javascript and its working fine in chrome, firefox and ie9 but not working in ie8. This is my code. Is there any alternate method for ie8.

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
```

Comment: [IE8 doesn't have SVG support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg).  Not sure if that has anything to do with this question, though.

Comment: Then how raphaeljs is working in ie8 any idea.

Comment: I don't know what raphaeljs is.

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/9869112/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869112/i-need-compatible-javascript-code-for-document-createelementns-in-older-versio) i tried this link no use.

Answer (score 2):

this might help you. what you want int supported by ie 8
https://github.com/shawnbot/aight